How to force Maven with Spring repackage to add the compiled packages to the jar root?
I've got some code in a module named "Electricity-aWattar". Injection and instantiation is controlled by Spring 3.4.0.
The artifact has got several main methods and one of this classes shall be defined to the MANIFEST to allow for simple invocation via "java -jar aWattar.jar".
But I need this artifact also to be used as a dependency to another module. This requires the classes of "Electricity-aWattar" to be available at the root of the "Electricity-aWattar" jarfile.
To enforce placement of the classes there I currently specify in pom.xml:
 <properties>
    <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
</properties>

But this suppresses MANIFEST-creation.
With the the above 'properties' specified the layout of the jar looks like this

When removing the 'properties'-statement from the pom, the jar looks like this:

Any idea how to get both - MANIFEST and generated classes at root in jar?
The maven packaging is forced by the pom.xml parameter:
<build>
    <finalName>aWattar</finalName>
    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>de.gombers.electricity.awattar.MainDataGatherer</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>


Since when Spring is an Apache project??

You are doing it wrong. You use normally build jar as lib, and repackage as runnabe jar. Period.

Don't use images for the context of a text file. Paste the context as text.

Also spring boot is not spring and  neither are from Apache. Edit your question to clarify.
